# Spring batch JobExecutionListener doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've got a Spring batch job that works correctly; I've add a job listener to change the exit status of the application but the job never goes inside the listener ( beforeJob and afterJob are never called). This is a part of my code:

```
@Bean(name = "myJob")
public Job myJob(@Qualifier("initStep") Step initStep,
        @Qualifier("firstStep") Step firstStep,
        @Qualifier("onSuccessStep") Step onSuccessStep) {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
            .listener(new JobExecutionListener() {
                @Override
                public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
                    ExitStatus exitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus() ;

                    if(exitStatus != ExitStatus.COMPLETED ){
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            })
            .start(initStep)
            .next(firstStep)
            .next(onSuccessStep)
            .build();
}
```

The job starts and ends correctly, but it never goes inside the listener; any suggestion?

Comment: Unfortunately cannot help with the listener not being executed (this code works for me). Just be aware the ExitStatus is not an enum and so you must compare their exitCode properties with equals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code shared works for me. But you can try alternate implementations like below to check if that works for you,

Snippet to show a sample job config with the listener,

```
Job job = jobBuilderFactory.get("jobName").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
    .start(step1()).next(step2()).next(step3()).next(step4).end()
    .listener(jobCompletionListener()).build();

@Bean
public JobCompletionListener jobCompletionListener() {
    return new JobCompletionListener();
}
```

Snippet of JobCompletionListener implementation,

```
public class JobCompletionListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCompletionListener.class);

   @Override
   public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
       if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
           logger.info("Job execution completed successfully");
       } else {
           logger.error("Job Execution Failed");
       }
   }
}
```